# programming languages android iphone ipad windows mobile windows phone

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, windows-phone-7, programming-languages

I'm wondering which programming language are supported by which mobile platform.

Please fill in the list below (native languages and third-party are possible too):

- **Android** languages:

  - abc *[native]*
  - def *[third-party with link]*
- **iPhone** languages:

  - abc *[native]*
  - def *[third-party with link]*
- **iPad** languages:

  - abc *[native]*
  - def *[third-party with link]*
- **Windows Mobile** languages:

  - abc *[native]*
  - def *[third-party with link]*
- **Windows Phone** languages:

  - abc *[native]*
  - def *[third-party with link]*

Comment: Tags belong in the tags field, not the title field...

Comment: Found to many different answers; just wanted a place where a list would be available. I understand that the third-parties will change over time, but the native languages don't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android 
-java
iphone 
-objective c
ipad 
-objective c
Windows mobile 
-Visual c++
Windows phone
-c#
```

Comment: A very simple example: Android is natively C/C++ (sic) and supports other languages like Ruby and Python. Windows Phone actually can use any .Net based language. iPad and iPhone can use the MonoTouch lib and therefore the .Net language family. That's why I say this is a Google homework.